# Got "Opening Handshake Failed" when trying to run webtransport samples locally

Tags: go, quic, http3, webtransport, quic-go

I've been trying to run some of the samples of the implementation of WebTransport, like

- https://github.com/quic-go/webtransport-go/tree/master/interop
- https://github.com/streaming-university/public-moq-demo/tree/main
- https://github.com/adriancable/webtransport-go-example

But all of the samples got the same error when I tried accessing them through the browser, which is "Opening Handshake Failed".

[Opening Handshake Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxB7v.png)

I created a self-signed certificate using this command

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout cert.key \
-x509 -out cert.pem -subj '/CN=Test Certificate' \
-addext "subjectAltName = DNS:localhost"
```

I ran them through wsl2 and accessed the client from Google Chrome Canary version 121. I added these flags just like what's mentioned in the comments [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/webtransport/webtransport_server.py).

```
--origin-to-force-quic-on=localhost:4443 localhost:1234 --allow-insecure-localhost --ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list=47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=
```

Has anyone had this problem, or knows what I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a major headache for me the last few days as well trying to get simple proofs of concept spun up.

You mention you are using wsl2 -- that's the failure point. wsl2 does not support forwarding fragmented UDP packets, https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6351 . It looks like in some cases people have had luck with `[experimental]` settings for `networkingMode=mirrored` and `hostAddressLoopback=true`, that didn't seem to be the case as far as I've tried.

You need to target your WSL2 IP, e.g. 172.6.2.1 (`ip addr show eth0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}'` in WSL)

A few additional things--as far as I understand, RSA keys are not supported. The way I was able to successfully connect to a local QUIC / WebTransport server was the following:

1. Generating a pair of ECDSA keys that are valid <14 days via `openssl req -new -newkey ec -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:prime256v1 -x509 -nodes -days 10 -out ./certificate.pem -keyout ./certificate.key -subj '/CN=Test Certificate' -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:localhost"`
2. Compute base64 hash of public key with `openssl x509 -in certificate.pem | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64`
3. Start server and use those keys for tls options.
4. Connect in the repl without horsing around with Chrome flags:

```js
function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binaryString = atob(base64);
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
const wt = new WebTransport('https://{WSL_IP}:{PORT}/counter', {
        serverCertificateHashes: [
          {
            algorithm: 'sha-256',
            value: base64ToArrayBuffer('{BASE64_HASH}')
          }
        ]
      });
```

FWIW I'm using https://github.com/adriancable/webtransport-go implementation since it currently supports datagrams. I am still new to the whole ecosystem and it all seems difficult and flaky to set up. There is a current issue logged in the *other* webtransport-go repo here https://github.com/quic-go/webtransport-go/issues/112 where someone on mac arm64 can't connect in the same way. I was still able to successfully get a connection with the WSL IP and WebTransport options in regular Chrome, no canary or flags necessary.